# ios Push notification from asp .net

Tags: asp.net, ios, apple-push-notifications

I try to send notification message from server,

when I try with php its working fine, but in .Net its not working. I'm using [MoonAPNS](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-and-c-%E2%80%93-part-4-apns-sharp-c-wrapper-class/),

I'm not using https server, just run in localhost.

I'm getting error as

A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.

```
An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckThrow(Boolean authSucessCheck)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.get_SecureStream()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at MoonAPNS.PushNotification.SendQueueToapple(IEnumerable`1 queue) in D:\Sample\PushNotification to iPhone\Moon-APNS-master\Moon-APNS-master\Application\MoonApns\PushNotification.cs:line 128
   at MoonAPNS.PushNotification.SendToApple(List`1 queue) in D:\Sample\PushNotification to iPhone\Moon-APNS-master\Moon-APNS-master\Application\MoonApns\PushNotification.cs:line 99
   at PushNotify._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Sample\PushNotification to iPhone\Moon-APNS-master\Moon-APNS-master\PushNotify\Default.aspx.cs:line 19
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

can any one help for this. any other way is there to send notification using .Net

Comment: Sorry, I try with some new certificate (*.certSigningRequest, *.cer, *.p12) Its working.